# Spring Data JPA Timestamp comparison

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, db2

i'm try to converting a native query into Specification. I'm stuck on this condition:

```
....
WHERE
TIMESTAMP(D_DATA, D_TIME) >= '2015-06-23 05:46:53.000000'
```

there is a way to obtain the same result with Specification?

Thank you

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: My Database is DB2

Comment: Also tell us what the types are for `D_DATA` and `D_TIME`.  My general feeling here is that your table should just store single timestamps, rather than separating date and time.

Comment: The types are Date and Time, and i cannot modify the table. I need to solve the problem from code.

Comment: The thing is, JPA doesn't really have much support for dates/times.  The `TIMESTAMP` function you are using is pretty much DB2 specific.  So, you may have to keep using your native query in this case, if you really can't change the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Paul Vernon, i resolved with:

```
public static Specification<Transit>compareTimestamps(Timestamp timestamp){
    LocalTime localTime = timestamp.toLocalDateTime().toLocalTime();
    LocalDate localDate = timestamp.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
    Specification<Transit> dateSpec = compareDateWithTimestamp(localDate);
    Specification<Transit> dateTimeSpec = compareDateAndTimeWithTimestamp(localDate, localTime);
    return where(dateSpec).or(dateTimeSpec);
}

private static <T>Specification<T> compareDateWithTimestamp(LocalDate localDate){
    return (Specification<T>) (root,query,cb) -> cb.greaterThan(root.get("dTrn"),localDate);
}
private static <T>Specification<T> compareDateAndTimeWithTimestamp(LocalDate localDate, LocalTime localTime){
    return (Specification<T>) (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("dTrn"),localDate));
        predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("dTimTrn"),localTime));
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it helps, but that filter could also be written like this in Db2.

```
WHERE
     D_DATA >= '2015-06-23'
OR ( D_DATA  = '2015-06-23' AND D_TIME >= '05:46:53' )
```